# How to check if Rectangle will fit inside another rectangle?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method that takes two rectangle parameters, and will return true if the first rectangle fits inside the second rectangle and false if it doesn't.

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
public class Square {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(0,0,100,200);
        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(0,0,100,200);
        fitsInside(rect1, rect2);
    }

    public static boolean fitsInside(Rectangle rec1, Rectangle rec2) {

        if (rec1.width < rec2.width && rec1.height < rec2.height) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile and run this code it returns nothing. Why does this not work and how I could fix it?

Comment: Note: Instead of writing `if(a) return true else return false`, you can also write `return a`. Apart from that, HyperNeutrino's answer is right.

Comment: While the others have already pointed out that your calculation is correct, I'd like to add that your current logic only checks if the rectangle fits into the other one without doing any rotation. For Example a rectangle with height 4 and width 2 would fit into another rectangle with height 3 and width 5, as long as you rotate it by 90degrees. I'll assume that not taking any rotations into consideration is probably what you want and the correct approach, but thought I would mention it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is right. The thing is you're not outputting your answer.

Surround the line where you call `fitsInside` with `System.out.println(...)` and it will display the result you're computing.

Answer (score 1):

The function `fitsInside` returns a boolean variable, but you are not using its return value. Since you haven't printed anything, you didn't get the result.

Printing the result will solve your problem:

```
System.out.println(fitsInside(rect1, rect2));
```